# Can I use applicationDirPath() to access resources at a higher directory level?

Tags: c++, qt

In the application that I am developing (using C++ and Qt), I am using **QApplication::applicationDirPath()** to access some resources, with respect of the application's path.

As an example, since I want to open a HTML manual from the application, I act this way:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionHelp_triggered()
{
    QString link = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Guide/guide.html";
    bool r = QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(link));
}
```

This snippet works if the project's structure presents the path "ProjectName/bin/Release/Guide/guide.html" (since the .exe file is in "ProjectName/bin/Release/AppName.exe").

But what can I do to refer to a higher-directory-level resource? As an example, I wish my HTML file to be in "ProjectName/data/Guide/guide.html". But this way, it seems not possible to compose the path in the way I'm acting.

**EDIT**: After @olive's comment, I wish to clarify a thing:
"**Why am I not using '../'?**"
Because it won't work from Visual Studio, where I am massively launch the application to test it. From VS, in fact, I shall use "../data/Guide/guide.html", when "from the outside", I'd have to do "../../data/Guide/guide.html".

That's why (I think) QApplication::applicationDirPath() exists. However, I am not an expert, so don't blame me and correct any eventual mistake of mine, please!

Comment: Can you try with "..\..\data/Guide/guide.html"?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, olive, but it's not what I'm looking for, *if possible*. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `..`. `QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/../../data/Guide/guide.html"` is perfectly valid path!

Of course there is another problem. When the application is installed, the relative path will probably be different again. You either need to configure the paths in visual studio so that the relative path works both during development and after deployment, or you need to detect the layout.

Comment: Thank you Jan!!! I suspected that it could work that way too, but I was omitting the first slash...This way, moreover, it works both from VS than from the bin path. I would follow your advice, BTW, and see that paths' configuration that you was speaking about.

Comment: @BiG: You can configure where the binary is placed in _Project Properties_ either setting _Output Directory_ in _General_ tab or _Output File_ in _Linker/General_ tab (hm, that's VS2008, I am not sure about VS2010). You can also set the working directory in _Debugging_ tab, but being independent of it using `applicationDirPath` is better.

Comment: I'm using VS2010, and I confirm that it works in the same way! Thank you so much...Again ;-)