# Qt QColumnView Adjust Columns to Contents' Width and Change Checkboxes' Images

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox

I am experimenting with QColumnView to implement re-sizable columns. There are three (3) problems that I faced.

1. The columns cannot be adjusted automatically accordingly to the contents' width. The columns are fixed at a certain width. Can I allow the columns to adjust to the contents' width or I can define a fixed width for the column?
2. If I click on the supposedly last (second) column (i.e. "Component 1 Item 1"), it still automatically expands into the third column. How can I stop it from expanding into another column (which is blank)?
3. I could not change the image of checkbox's checked and unchecked states. The images do not show up. The size is 40x40, but the images are blank.

Please help.

Thanks.

```
void SetDialog::createLayout() {
    this->setStyleSheet("QListView::indicator { width: 40; height: 40; }"
    "QListView::indicator::checked { image: url(../Icons/Checkbox_Checked.png); }"
    "QListView::indicator::unchecked { image: url(../Icons/Checkbox_Unchecked.png); }");

    ...

    page1ColumnView = new QColumnView(page1);
    page1ColumnView->setFixedSize(772, 400);

    QStandItemModel *model = new QStandItemModel;

    QStandardItem *component1 = new QStandardItem("Component 1");
    QStandardItem *component2 = new QStandardItem("Component 2");
    model->appendRow(component1);
    model->appendRow(component2);

    QStandardItem *component1Item1 = new QStandardItem("Component 1 Item 1");
    QStandardItem *component1Item2 = new QStandardItem("Component 1 Item 2");
    component1Item1->setCheckable(true);
    component1Item2->setCheckable(true);
    component1->appendRow(component1Item1);
    component1->appendRow(component1Item2);

    QStandardItem *component2Item1 = new QStandardItem("Component 2 Item 1");
    QStandardItem *component2Item2 = new QStandardItem("Component 2 Item 2");
    component2Item1->setCheckable(true);
    component2Item2->setCheckable(true);
    component1->appendRow(component2Item1);
    component1->appendRow(component2Item2);

    ... }
```

Comment: Regarding the 3rd point, maybe you can't see the images 'cause the application cannot solve your relative paths: you should use applicationDirPath(). See here for an "instant" example of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459521/can-i-use-applicationdirpath-to-access-resources-at-a-higher-directory-level

For the 1st point, have you tried using setColumnWidths()? (http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qcolumnview.html#setColumnWidths)

And, at least for me, 2nd point is not much clear...

Comment: @BiG: Thanks. I am trying out setColumnWidths(). However, I do not have an idea how to declare the list iterator. `setColumnWidths(const QList<int> &list>`. What do I need to declare?

Comment: I think that's a list containing the sizes of each column. Roughly speaking, you can scan all the columns' contents for obtain their lengths, and use those lengths to specify each column's size.

To iterate through a QList, you can do something like this:

          `QList<int>::iterator i;

          for (i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)

              cout << (*i);`

Let me know if this addresses your needs...